# Datatable (DT) Shiny - > steps for the slider range in filters

Tags: jquery, r, datatable

i am having a problem with datatable filter. My data is very big (> 5000000 rows), including some numerical and factor columns. Datatable uses to filter the numerical column slider, everything would be great if not the "steps" of the range. **Is there any way to make the steps more finer**?

Example code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

x <- as.numeric(1:1000000)
y <- as.numeric(1:1000000)
data <- data.frame(x,y)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput('tbl'),
                 plotOutput('plot1')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDataTable({
      datatable(data, filter = "top", options = list(
        pageLength = 300, lengthMenu = c(100,200,300,400,500,600)
      ))
    })
    output$plot1 = renderPlot({
      filtered_data <- input$tbl_rows_all
      ggplot(data = filtered_data, aes(x = x,y = y)) + geom_line()
    })
  }
)
```

Thanks for the help!

Cheers

Can i use somehow JQuery? I found this question on stackoverflow [which might be usefull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600338/using-jqueryui-slider-to-range-filter-datatable-results/%22here%22), however i dont know how i can implement it to my datatable.

Comment: Trying to replicate what you are doing. can you tell me what do you mean to make steps more finer ? Is it the x-axis in plot ? btw...your table is not displayed when I run the script..it displays only the plot. `Filter = "top"` is basically a search box on top of the table displayed.

Comment: Hey, when i runApp it shows me the table of x and y with two filters (after clicking on them sliders come up) on top (respectively under x and y column names). Using the sliders to filter the data is hard (as long as the data is big), The ranges to choose are very limited, I would like the slider to be finer (using normal shiny widget, You are able to set the step value,as example: `sliderInput("decimal", "Decimal:", 
                min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5, step= 0.1)`). Is it possible to use the steps in `datatable` or at least make the slider ranges more finer?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter on server side not in DT

1) Add `sliderInput` for each numeric column ( may be using `loop` or `lapply`)

2) create `reactive` for subseting

3) render subseted data

for example

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

q <- as.numeric(1:1000)
w <- as.numeric(1:1000)
e <- as.numeric(1:1000)
r <- as.numeric(1:1000)
t <- as.numeric(1:1000)
y <- as.numeric(1:1000)
u <- as.numeric(1:1000)
i <- as.numeric(1:1000)
o <- as.numeric(1:1000)
data <- data.frame(q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(uiOutput("filter_ui")),
    dataTableOutput('tbl'),
    plotOutput('plot1')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$filter_ui = renderUI({
      lapply(colnames(data),function(i) {
        column(
          width = round(12 / ncol(data),0),sliderInput(
            paste0("s",i),min = min(data[[i]]),
            max = max(data[[i]]),step = 100 ,
            value = c(min(data[[i]]),max(data[[i]])),label = i
          )
        )
      })
    })
    data_1 = reactive({
      data_ = data
      for (i in colnames(data)) {
        data_ = data_[data_[[i]] <= input[[paste0("s",i)]][2] &
                       data_[[i]] >= input[[paste0("s",i)]][1],]
      }
      data_
    })

    output$tbl = renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(data_1(), options = list(
        pageLength = 300, lengthMenu = c(100,200,300,400,500,600)
      ))
    })
    output$plot1 = renderPlot({
      ggplot(data = data_1(), aes(x = q,y = w)) + geom_line()
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice, however, my ShinyApp, which i am working with, is much bigger (having >10 columns with sliders and so on), so i would love to have it done (**if its possible**) on DT side

Comment: Edit my variant for lapply creating `sliderinput` and for more colums ( plot only two first)

Comment: Thanks but i really need to do it on **datatable side**, it is much more convenient for me at this moment. My original ShinyApp is composed of datatable with filters for each column, after filtering,data is displayed on few graphs (plus user chooses x and y axis, change hist binwidth, etc etc)so it will be way too much widgets

Comment: Simply i think that render DT with 10^6 rows not good idea( too long processing), you realy not need slider for all colums( for example you can add multiple selectinput and the add filters only for selected column on server side).

Comment: I agree with You fully, however this ShinyApp is for one of the departments at  company i work for, and they have decided what they wanna see, so i do not have much freedom...